# How to extract unique values from an array EXCEPT specified values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am already abel to extract unique values, in excel, from an array using this function:

`{=INDEX(list,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(uniques,list),0))}`

However, I want to specify certain values for excel not to return. Is there any way to specify values that I don't want to be found within the already specified "list"? The ideal outome would be something like this:

[image: excel list example]

I am also using excel version 2101.

Any information is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is. And it is easier in O365 vs earlier versions of Excel. If you need help as to how to do it, I suggest you EDIT your question to include an example of your data (preferably as text that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet), along with your expected results.  It might help to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also include the Excel version you are using, and whether it is Windows or MAC or Online

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the info, I just made some edits. I couldn't copy and paste the data directly without creating an image link, but I hope this is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I ASSUME you want to exclude the lines starting with `Round`.

Try:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(List),FILTER(x,LEFT(x,5)<>"Round"))
```

or

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(List,(LEFT(List,5)<>"Round")))
```

I'm not sure if it is more efficient to filter a smaller list, as is done in the first formula; or to avoid using `LET` as is done in the second formula.

**EDIT**

This can also be done using `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN` which should be present in all **Windows** versions 2016+

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,list)&"</s></t>","//s[not(starts-with(.,'Round')) and not(preceding-sibling::*=.)]")
```

***the xPath***

- `not(starts-with(.,'Round'))` : should be obvious
- Return only unique values:

  - `and not(preceding-sibling::*=.)` : do not return a node if any `preceding-sibling` matches the current node being tested

Comment: Sadly my build of Excel does not include either LET or FILTER. I'm using build 13628.20380 Maybe there is an add-on that I am missing?

Comment: @ChapinCheney At "About Excel" mine says `Version 2101 (Build 13628.20380 Click-to-Run) Current Channel`. If I click "About Excel", it then shows `Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13628.20128) 32-bit` Perhaps you have an Enterprise version which hasn't been brought up to date yet?

Comment: @ChapinCheney See my edit for a formula version not using `LET` or `FILTER` or `UNIQUE`

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly. Took a little playing around to understand completely, but honestly thank you